# Identify the class of language?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, pi, regular-language

Given a set

$$S=\{x∣ \text{there is an x-block of 5's in the decimal expansion of π}\}$$

(Note: x-block is a maximal block of x successive 5's).

Identify class of language?

---

Somewhere it explained : S is regular. It might not be possible to find what is x, but once it is found, it will be an integer and hence can be represented using an automaton.

My question is :

> Since,there is infinite digits in expansion of $\pi$, so , how we recognize $x$?

Comment: Certainly it's semi-decidable.

Comment: @BrianO, Semi -decidable means recursive enumerable but not recursive, rt?

Comment: Not quite. Semi-decidable means recursively enumerable (r.e.), decidable means recursive. A recursive set is also r.e. of course. I'm not sure if this set is decidable or not. If a TM is asked, "Is $5283\in S$?" and there is no run of exactly $5283$ 5's in $\pi$, then it will search forever (won't halt).

Comment: If $\pi$ were known to be "[normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number)", then we could do better. But to the best of my knowledge, (non-)normality remains unproven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty likely to be open, if $\pi$ is proved normal the set would be all positive integers.

We know the language is recursively enumerable but there aren't known techniques to show it is recursive.

If you change the definition of "x-block" from "a maximal block of consecutive 5's" to "a block of consecutive 5's", then the language is regular. Proof: either the length of blocks is unbounded (then $L$ contains all positive integers), or the length of blocks is bounded by a number $N$ (then $L$ is finite).